# d3.classed() with multiple selections

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am trying to `select` multiple classes and use `.class()` to remove a class from them.

It's not working.

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

```
d3.selectAll(".app-map-charts-circles0 .app-map-charts-circles1 .app-map-charts-circles2 .app-map-charts-circles3")
                .classed("app-map-charts-circles-active", false);
```

Comment: have you tried using d3.select rather than selectAll?

Comment: I believe I did yes without success.

Comment: Remove the spaces in the selector string if you want the elements that have all of these classes.

Comment: Do you mean this: `d3.selectAll(".app-map-charts-circles0, .app-map-charts-circles1, .app-map-charts-circles2, .app-map-charts-circles3").classed(...` ? Coma separate classes to select all elements classed with one of mentioned class

Comment: Like jQuery, d3 uses standard CSS selectors. Ultimately d3 feeds your selector into a `.querySelectorAll(selector)` statement. If you want to understand how the selector will work therefore, study the standard CSS specification.

Comment: Are you trying to select nodes with **all** of those classes or nodes with **any** of those classes? It's not really clear, it would be good if you edit your question to clarify...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate distinct classes with comma. If using spaces, that will find nested selections.

Correctly written, it is:

```
d3.selectAll(".app-map-charts-circles0, .app-map-charts-circles1, .app-map-charts-circles2, .app-map-charts-circles3").classed(...
```